# MLE coin toss problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Given a coin with an unknown bias and the observation of $N$ heads and $0$
tails, what is expected probability that the next flip is a **head**?

i want to solve with **MLE**, not Bayesian analysis.

My attempt:

For any value of p , the probability of k Heads in n tosses is given by

$\binom{n}{k} p^k \left ( 1-p \right )^{n-k}$

Consider the maximization problem:

$\frac{\partial p^k \binom{n}{k} (1-p)^{n-k}}{\partial p}=0$

$\hat{p}=\frac{k}{n}$

and I'm stuck here. Thank you.

Answer: $\frac{n+1}{n+2}$

Comment: What does Ans mean?

Comment: sorry, i edited.

Comment: Not sure what you hope to get out of Maximum Liklihood. Clearly the probabilty with the highest probability of getting $N$ out of $N$ Heads is $p=1$.  So what?

Comment: The probability of $k$ Heads in $N$ tosses; I expected probability that the next flip is a HEAD. Bayesian estimate works here, we can find but so hard. That's why I want to find log likelihood parameter estimation. Not bayesian estimate.

Comment: $\frac{n+1}{n+2}$ is the mean of the Bayesian posterior distribution starting with a uniform prior and is not difficult.  But you have excluded that approach

Comment: Based on the observed data, the maximum likelihood estimate of $p$ is $p=1$. Using this value of $p$, the probability of getting heads on the next toss is $1$. As Lulu pointed out, it seems strange to attempt to use maximum likelihood estimation here.

Comment: but I solved @littleO :)

Comment: jekyll - your solution has an error: you say the likelihood is proportional to $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ but then you take the derivative of $p^{k+1}(1-p)^{n-k+1}$

Comment: @Henry I used the likelihood is proportional to the beta distribution, with parameters. $k+1$ and $n-k+1$ which was $n=k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we observe $k=N$ heads in $N$ trials and want to determine the unknown probability $p$ and the accuracy of the estimate. The maximum likelihood estimate is the value of $p$ giving the largest probability for the observed data.

$0\leq p\leq 1$

$Unif(0, 1)$ and the beta distribution where $α = 1$, $β = 1$ in our case.

Lets find the posterior distribution of p for a prior, π(p) ∼ Beta(α, β)

$\pi (p)=\frac{1}{B(\alpha ,\beta )}p^{\alpha -1}\left ( 1-p \right )^{\beta -1}$

$f(k|p)=\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$

$f(p|k)=\frac{f(k|p)}{f_{K}k}\pi(p)$

$\propto p^{k+\alpha -1}(1-p)^{n-k+\beta -1}$

Based on this we can see that $f(p|k)$ has a **Beta(k+α, n−k+β)** distribution.

so $\beta=1$ and $\alpha=1$

the likelihood is proportional to the **beta distribution**, with parameters $k+1$ and $n-k+1$.

In our problem $N$ Heads in $N$ tosses.
**N=k**

This partial derivative is $0$ at the maximum likelihood estimates;

$\frac{\partial p^{k+1} (1-p)^{n-k+1}}{\partial p}=0$

$p=\frac{k+1}{n+2}$

$n=k$ $\Rightarrow$  $p=\frac{n+1}{n+2}$

(Note that it isn’t necessary to find $f_K(k)$ explicitly and we can ignore the normalizing constants of both the Likelihood and Prior.)

Answer (score 1):

Really not sure what you mean by Maximum Likelihood in your context, but here goes an attemp. Let $Z_n$ be the even that the first $n$ flips are all heads and $H_n$ be the $n$th coin turning out head, then we are interested in $P(H_{n+1} \vert Z_n)$, which is given as follows
\begin{equation}
 P(H_{n+1} \vert Z_n)
 =
 \sum_{i=0}^n
 P(H_{n+1} \vert Z_n A_i)P(A_i \vert Z_n) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Assuming that the flipping trials are independent conditioning on the $i^{th}$ coin being the chosen one, then
\begin{equation}
 P(H_{n+1} \vert Z_n A_i)
 =
 \frac{i}{k}
\end{equation}
Using Bayes theorem, we can say
\begin{equation}
 P(A_i \vert Z_n) = \frac{P(Z_n \vert A_i)P(A_i)}{P(Z_n)}
 =
 \frac{\frac{1}{k+1}(\frac{i}{k})^n}{\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^k (\frac{j}{k})^n}
=
\frac{(\frac{i}{k})^n}{\sum_{j=0}^k (\frac{j}{k})^n}
\end{equation}
Replacing in $(1)$, we get
\begin{equation}
 P(H_{n+1} \vert Z_n)
 =
\sum_{i=0}^n
 P(H_{n+1} \vert Z_n A_i)P(A_i \vert Z_n)
=
\sum_{i=0}^n
 \frac{i}{k}\frac{(\frac{i}{k})^n}{\sum_{j=0}^k (\frac{j}{k})^n}
=
 \frac{\sum_{i=0}^k (\frac{i}{k})^{n+1}}{\sum_{i=0}^k (\frac{i}{k})^n} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
and we're done.

---

### For large $k$

As $k \rightarrow \infty$, the sum becomes an integral, therefore
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}
 =
 \frac{1}{k}
 \sum_{i=0}^k
 (\frac{i}{k})^{\beta}
 =
 \int_0^1
 x^\beta \ dx
 =
 \frac{1}{1+\beta}
\end{equation}
For $\beta = n+1$ in the numerator of $(2)$ and $\beta=n$ for the denominator in $(2)$, we get
\begin{equation}
 P(H_{n+1} \vert Z_n)
 =
 \frac{n+1}{n+2}
\end{equation}

As $n \rightarrow \infty$, we can see that the probability becomes $1$, which is intuitive.

Comment: thanks, but  we observed n tossing of a unknown biased coin with probability of heads being θ.  How can I calculate this parameter via maximum likelihood? How can I derive the log-likelihood formula and the correct maximum likelihood estimate of θ? I was trying to find Likelihood function.. @AhmadBazzi